# Plotting Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python

I loaded a csv and extracted a time series which I put into a new dataframe. However, I cant seem to do anything with it, not pct_change nor plotting it..this is what I did [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5kAo.png)

and this is the error I get [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWgYC.png)

changed commas and dots around, but nothing works

Comment: I think you have to convert the data to `float` before you plot it.

Answer (score 0):

"1630,92" is a string, not a float number or a integer number, you should split it and get the column you want to plot.

Comment: Do you mean split the whole dataframe? or split the number(or rather string)?

Comment: split the string to numbers

Answer (score 0):

maybe one or all your data are string
so convert them to float before plot them

```
sen2['feature name']=pd.to_numeric(sen2['feature name'])
```

and change the , to .

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem using the command `sen2=sen2.astype(float)` as well as

```
sen2=sen2.replace(',', '.', regex=True)
```